# Supplementary character support in Java web application with Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jsp, supplementary

I am able to enter supplementary chars in textbox but it doesn't get save in database. I am using MySql database. I have used spring and hibernate in my application. What change should I make to enable supplementary chars support in my application?

Following is my database connection string:

```
url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8"
```

Comment: which encoding does your mysql schema and table definition use?

Answer (score 2):

You need to do following changes to make your application supplementary character compatible:

1. Remove characterEncoding i.e. utf8 from your url and make it as below:

   url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users?useUnicode=true"
2. You need to edit my.ini file from MySQL Server directory. If you have Windows 64bit OS, then you may find it at following location:

   C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini

Open this file using any text editor such as Notepad++ and change the following parameter value:

From

```
character-set-server=utf8
```

To

```
character-set-server=utf8mb4
```

After making the above changes your application should support Supplementary characters.